# Products and Relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I hope somebody can help me with this problem that I am having please!

I don't know how to solve this question.

On the set $Z$ (the set of integers) the relation $R$ is given by $xRy$ if and only if $x + y$ is even (i.e. $x + y$ is divisible by
$2$)

Discuss whether $R$ is an equivalence relation and show a matrix and digraph
representation of the relation $R$ on the subset of $Z$, $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and suggest equivalence classes, if appropriate.

Comment: Check each of the properties of being an equivalence relation.  Is it reflexive?  (*is $xRx$ for all $x$?  I.e. is $x+x$ even for all $x$*)  Is it symmetric?  (*if $xRy$ that implies $x+y$ is even.  Does this imply then that $yRx$?  I.e. if $x+y$ is even does that mean $y+x$ is even as well?*)  Is it transitive?  (*i'll let you remember for yourself the definition here.  look in your notes*)

Answer (score 1):

Check the following three facts:

$aRa$ (true, $2a$ is even)

$aRb \iff bRa$ (true)

If $aRb$ and $bRc$, is $aRc$? (true). To see this, if $a$ is an odd number, then $aRb$ requires $b$ to be odd as well; $bRc$ then requires $c$ to be odd too. Thus $aRc$ is true, as $a+c$ is even (summation of two odd numbers). Similarly if $a$ is even, then $b$ and $c$ are even as well. Thus we still get $aRc$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $x+y$ is even if and only if $x$ and $y$ have the same parity (ie if $x$ is odd, then $y$ is also odd, and if $x$ is even, then $y$ is also even).  Thus, $xRy$ iff $x$ and $y$ have the same parity. It is clear that $x$ and $x$ have the same parity, whence $R$ is reflexive.  If $x$ and $y$ have the same parity, then so do $y$ and $x$, and so $R$ is symmetric.  Finally, if $x$ and $y$ have the same parity and $y$ and $z$ have the same parity, then $x$ and $z$ have the same parity. Hence, $R$ is transitive.  Thus, $R$ is an equivalence relation on the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers.

Every equivalence relation gives rise to a partition. If the ground set is $\mathbb{Z}$, then the partition is the set of even integers and the set of odd integers.  If the ground set is $\{1,2,3,4\}$, then $R$ partitions this ground set into $\{1,3\}$ and $\{2,4\}$.